# touchesMovedなどでのタッチイベント時に取得した値を他のfuncで使用したい

Tags: swift, ios

touchMovedなどで取得した値を他のfuncなどに値を渡したい場合、どの様にしたら良いのでしょうか。
例えば以下の様なコードのpositionの値を他のfuncで扱いたい場合です。

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        for coalescedTouch in event!.coalescedTouches(for: touch)! {
            let position = coalescedTouch.location(in: self)
            print(position.x, position.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 正直言って、どの部分に困難を感じておられるのかがよくわかりません。うまく動かない部分があっても構いませんので、現在までに書かれたコード(あるいは現在の知識で書くとこんなふうになるだろうと言うコード)をお示しいただいた上で、どんな風にうまくいかないのかを記述されると、あなたが欲しい回答、をより早く得ることにつながります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まだまだよくわからない点があるので、あなたの期待する回答にはなっていないかもしれませんが、その場合にはコメント等でお知らせください。

「他のfuncなどに値を渡したい」のであれば、その値を保持するインスタンスプロパティをクラス内に持つのが一番妥当でしょう。

あなたのコード例をそのまま使うとこんな感じになります。

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var positions: [CGPoint]? //<-インスタンスプロパティを定義

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            positions = [] //空配列で初期化
            for coalescedTouch in event!.coalescedTouches(for: touch)! {
                let position = coalescedTouch.location(in: self)
                print(position.x, position.y)
                positions?.append(position) //値を追加
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(`positions`に値を設定すればいいだけならfor-inは要らないのですが、とりあえずそのままにしておきます。)

後は`positions`プロパティを読み取れば良いだけなので、同じクラス内の「他のfunc」から普通にアクセスできますし、`MyView`のインスタンスにアクセスできるなら別クラスからでも`theView.positions`みたいな感じでアクセスできます。

(追記)コメントに書いたように、最初の1個だけアクセスできれば良いのなら、こんな感じです。

```
        if let position = theView.positions?.first {
            print(position) //<-`position`は`CGPoint`型
        } else {
            print("positions not ready")
        }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご連絡遅れましてすいません。他のfuncから読むことには成功したのですが、Cannot convert value of type '[CGPoint]?' to expected argument type 'CGPoint'というエラーにより使用することができておりません。これは型の変換等が必要ということでしょうか。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @x001017 さん、丁寧なコメントありがとうございます。`'[CGPoint]?'`と言うのは、`CGPoint`の`Array`の`Optional`ですから、まずは **_(安全に)unwrapする_**、そして、**_(配列の中から)1つの要素を選ぶ_** ことが必要です。例えば「いつでも最初の1つで良い」と言う場合のコード例を回答の最後に追記しておきますので、参考にして下さい。

Comment: お忙しいところありがとうございます。追記のほどもありがとうございます。現状、使用したい事につきましては、同じクラス内ではあるのですが`let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: positions.x, y: positions.y)`のように普通に扱えたらと考えております。宜しくお願い致します

Comment: @x001017 さん、何を持って「普通」と言うのかわかりませんが、あなたの元コードはfor-inで複数の位置を扱うようになっています。まずはそこを普通にしてもらわないと、これ以上はなんとも言えません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。先ずはfor-in自体が複数という事で、多分その事自体がよくわかっていないと思っております。そこの解説からしていただけますと幸いです。タッチされた時のcoalescedTouchesのxの値とyの値を取得したいというのが基本です。その値を他のfuncで扱えればと考えて御質問をしてしまったのですが、coalescedTouchesはfor-inで書くのが普通だと思っておりました。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @x001017 さん、for-inがわからないと言うことであれば配列(やSequence)など、Swift言語の基礎がわかっていないと言うことになります。「coalescedTouchesはfor-inで書くのが普通」だからfor-inを使うのではありません。「`coalescedTouches(for:)`の値は配列で、そのすべての要素に対して処理を行いたいからfor-inを使う」のです。プログラミング言語の基礎を学ぶにはこのサイトは不向きですので、実際のコードを書く前に、他のサイトや書籍できちんと基礎を学習されるようお勧めします。